# Actual and formal argument lists differ in length using super

Tags: java, xcode, oop, object, syntax-error

Whenever I try to call the super for the parent class constructor, I get the following error:

> actual and formal argument lists differ in length

The error takes place at the super statement.

This is my parent class:

```
public class Person {
    protected String name,adress,phone,cell;
    protected dateofbirth dob;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person{" + "name=" + name + ", adress=" + adress + ", phone=" + phone + ", cell=" + cell + ", dob=" + dob + '}';
    }

    public Person(String name, String adress, String phone, String cell, dateofbirth dob) {
        this.name = name;
        this.adress = adress;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.cell = cell;
        this.dob = dob;
    }
```

and this is the subclass:

```
public class employee extends Person {
    private int ID,extension;
    private double salary;

    public employee(int ID,int extension,double salary,String name,dateofbirth dob,String adress,String phone,String cell){
      super(name,adress,phone,cell,dob);
      this.ID=ID;
      this.extension=extension;
      this.salary=salary;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "employee{" + "ID=" + ID + ", extension=" + extension + ", salary=" + salary +super.toString()+'}';
    }

    public int getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public void setID(int ID) {
        this.ID = ID;
    }

    public void setExtension(int extension) {
        this.extension = extension;
    }

    public void setSalary(double salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public int getExtension() {
        return extension;
    }

    public double getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the code you posted here is the actual code you are compiling? Perhaps you got this error in an older version of one of your classes.

Comment: copy pasted code from question (Eclipse). problem does not recreate...

Comment: i am using netbeans 8.0.2 perhaps its the netbeans itself?

Comment: Perhaps you should clean and rebuild your project.